# Killing child processes from parent's signal handler hangs

Tags: process, posix

I have a problem in topic of posix processes and I can't get around.

I have a process which forks several children (the process tree can be complex, not only one level). It also keeps track of the active childrens' PID. At some point the parent receives a signal (SIGINT, let's say).

In the signal handler for SIGINT, it iterates over the list of child processes and sends the same signal to them in order to prevent zombies. Now, the problem is that

1. if the parent does not waitpid() for the child to be stopped, the signal seems to be never dispatched (zombies keep running)
2. if the parent waits after every kill() sent to a child, it simply hangs there and the child seems to ignore the signal

Parent and children have the same signal handler, as it's installed before forking.
Here is a pseudocode.

```
signal_handler( signal )
    foreach child in children
        kill( child, signal )
        waitpid( child, status )

    // Releasing system resources, etc.
    clean_up()

    // Restore signal handlers.
    set_signal_handlers_to_default()

    // Send back the expected "I exited after XY signal" to the parent by
    // executing the default signal handler again.
    kill( getpid(), signal )
```

With this implementation the execution stops on the waitpid. If I remove the waitpid, the children keep running.

My guess is that unless a signal handler has ended, the signals sent from it are not dispatched to the children. But why aren't they dispatched if I omit wait?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Looks like the children are stuck in the signal handler. What's the value of `children` in the children? What does `cleanup` do?

Comment: `childen` in children is empty if they are leaves (containing their children processes otherwise). Just after forking I empty this array in the child. `cleanup` is viod (empty) for the sake of debugging.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the disposition of SIGCHLD?

Comment: There is another wait in the same code executing regardless of the signal handler, that waits for all children to stop (not only one pid), but there is no signal handler for SIGCHLD set up.

Comment: Chances are if no one has come up with a compelling explanation thus far - I certainly haven't - you are going to have post some code.  Can you reduce the code to the smallest sample that recreates the problem?

Comment: Sure. I actually do the thing in PHP using the process control functions that mimic C functions (and I think they one-to-one map to them)
https://gist.github.com/1328530

The weird thing is that implementing it in C works perfectly, hitting CTRL+C kills children and then kills itself. In PHP children don't even respond to SIGINT.

Comment: If possible, execute a shell command that does 'kill -9 PID' or 'killall -9 process-name'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe should work and indeed it does, with the following testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define NCHILDREN 3
pid_t child [NCHILDREN];

struct sigaction sa, old;

static void
handler (int ignore)
{
  int i;

  /* Kill the children.  */
  for (i = 0; i < NCHILDREN; ++i)
    {
      if (child [i] > 0)
        {
          kill (child [i], SIGUSR1);
          waitpid (child [i], 0, 0);
        }
    }

  /* Restore the default handler.  */
  sigaction (SIGUSR1, &old, 0);

  /* Kill self.  */
  kill (getpid (), SIGUSR1);
}

int
main ()
{
  int i;

  /* Install the signal handler.  */
  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction (SIGUSR1, &sa, &old);

  /* Spawn the children.  */
  for (i = 0; i < NCHILDREN; ++i)
    {
      if ((child [i] = fork ()) == 0)
        {
          /* Each of the children: clear the array, wait for a signal
             and exit.  */
          while (i >= 0)
            child [i--] = -1;
          pause ();
          return 0;
        }
    }

  /* Wait to be interrupted by a signal.  */
  pause ();
  return 0;
}
```

If you see the parent hanging in `waitpid`, it means the child has not exited. Try to attach with a debugger to see where the child is blocked, or, easier, run the program with `strace(1)`. How do you clean up your pid array? Make sure the children are not trying call `waitpid` with pid parameter being <= 0. Make sure the children are not blocking or ignoring the signal.

Comment: That worked for me too. You don't even need the waitpid() call. The reason without waitpid() call zombie still running is because the child is already blocked. That explains why the main process hangs when waitpid() is in place.